# How to do redirect and load the same component in Vue Router

Tags: javascript, redirect, vue.js, routes, vue-router

I am trying to create a route structure that would allow me to do the following.

- Home.vue has one router view
- `/home/clients` should load the **Clients** component
- `home/campaigns` should load the **Campaigns** component
- `home/clients/:id` should redirect to `/home/clients/:id/campaigns` and load the same **Campaigns** component.

I do not want to introduce another router view inside **Clients** component to handle the campaigns part. I was trying to get it done with following routes but really can't get it to work.

These are children routes to `/home`.

**UPDATE:** I got it working literally writing down every path that I may encounter. Is there a way I can elegantly solve this?

```
{
  path: '/home',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Home,
  beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
    if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
      next({
        path: '/login',
        query: {
          redirect: to.fullPath
        }
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  },
  children: [
    {
      path: 'clients',
      component: Clients
    },
    {
      path: 'clients/:clientId',
      redirect: 'clients/:clientId/campaigns'
    },
    {
      path: 'clients/:clientId/campaigns',
      component: Campaigns
    },
    {
      path: 'clients/:clientId/campaigns/:campaignId',
      redirect: 'clients/:clientId/campaigns/:campaignId/ads'
    },
    {
      path: 'clients/:clientId/campaigns/:campaignId/ads',
      component: Ads
    },
    {
      path: 'clients/:clientId/campaigns/:campaignId/ads/:adId',
      redirect: 'clients/:clientId/campaigns/:campaignId/ads/:adId/postings'
    },
    {
      path: 'clients/:clientId/campaigns/:campaignId/ads/:adId/postings',
      component: Postings
    },
    {
      path: 'campaigns',
      component: Campaigns
    },
    {
      path: 'campaigns/:campaignId',
      redirect: 'campaigns/:campaignId/ads'
    },
    {
      path: 'campaigns/:campaignId/ads',
      component: Ads
    },
    {
      path: 'campaigns/:campaignId/ads/:adId',
      redirect: 'campaigns/:campaignId/ads/:adId/postings'
    },
    {
      path: 'campaigns/:campaignId/ads/:adId/postings',
      component: Postings
    },
    {
      path: 'ads',
      component: Ads
    },
    {
      path: 'ads/:adId',
      redirect: 'ads/:adId/postings'
    },
    {
      path: 'ads/:adId/postings',
      component: Postings
    },
    {
      path: 'postings',
      component: Postings
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you use child routes, you need to use nested router views

Comment: I really do want to render them at the same router nesting level. It's just that I need to serve different routes. Please check the updated question to understand what I am trying to achieve.